# Function documentation duplicated on prototypes in C++ header files -> Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen repeats function documentation when it encounters function prototypes in
header files, for example:

code:

```
#include <File main.h>

void Func1(void);


///File main.c:

#include <main.h>

/*! Main program entry point. */
main()
{
    Func1();
}

/*! Test function which does nothing. */
void Func1(void)
{
    return;
}
```

generates two lots of documentation for Func1(): the first in the main.c
documentation, and the second in the main.h documentation. With a large project,
this almost doubles the size of the documentation with repeated, redundant
function documentation. Is this a bug or some configuration problem?

Comment: What values have you set for `INPUT=` and `FILE_PATTERNS=` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `NO` and only document your header files using (`/** @file */`) then doxygen will only show the headers and still include the documentation found at the function's definition.

If you document both header and source file or set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `YES`, then doxygen will show the documentation of the function as part of the header and as part of the source file documentation. This is feature, not a bug :-)

Comment: If documentation merges, what comes first, the header docs or the sources docs? (I guess header.)

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicate the function prototype and not the implementation. But maybe just setting `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS` to `YES` could fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure doxygen to group free functions by namespace, not by file.